# Disable Spark master's check for hostname equality

Tags: apache-spark, docker, hostname

I have a Spark-master running in a Docker container which in turn is executed on a remote server. Next to the Spark-master there are containers running Spark-slave on the same Docker Host.

`Server <---> Docker Host <---> Docker Container`

In order to let the slaves find the master, I set a master hostname in Docker `SPARKMASTER` which the slaves use to connect to the master. So far, so good.

I use the SPARK_MASTER_IP environment variable to let the master bind to that name.

I also exposed the Spark port 7077 to the Docker host and forwarded this port on the physical server host. The port is open and available.

Now on my machine I can connect to the Server using its IP, say 192.168.1.100. When my Spark program connects to the server on port 7077 I get a connection, which is disassociated by the master:

`15/10/09 17:13:47 INFO AppClient$ClientEndpoint: Connecting to master spark://192.168.1.100:7077...
15/10/09 17:13:47 WARN ReliableDeliverySupervisor: Association with remote system [akka.tcp://sparkMaster@192.168.1.100:7077] has failed, address is now gated for [5000] ms. Reason: [Disassociated]`

I already learned that the reason for this disconnection is that the host IP 192.168.1.100 doesn't match the hostname SPARKMASTER.

I could add a host to my /etc/hosts file which would probably work. But I don't want to do that. **Is there a way I can completely disable this check for hostname equality?**

Comment: Can the slaves talk to the executor?

Comment: By executor you mean the Spark master? Then yes, the slaves connect to the master perfectly fine. I checked the log files.

Comment: No, the executor is the jvm where you launch the `SparkContext`.

Comment: The snippet from the log is from the executor. Using nmap I checked whether the port is open - which it is. The slaves have to be able to talk to the executor?

Comment: Oops, it's called driver, and yes, they do. https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/cluster-overview.html

Comment: That's something I definately have to check. Thanks for the pointer.